# Сортировка QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Есть `QSortFilterProxyModel`, которая берет данные в `QSqlTableModel`.
Идея в том, чтобы сделать быстрее процесс сортировки, так как `SQL` запросы сами по себе тяжелые, особенно, если дело касается множественной фильтрации.

В чем же проблема? Как оказалось, `QSortFilterProxyModel` захватывает определенное количество данных при запросе, то есть захватывает не все сразу. Решил в лоб считывать данные с родителя модели до конца:

```
while(buildModel.canFetchMore()) buildModel.fetchMore();
```

но, как оказалось, полная считка данных тоже тормозит систему. Никто с таким не сталкивался?
Может быть кто-то подскажет, как облегчить весь процесс?

Comment: Выборка по условию из БД будет работать быстрее, чем `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Это связано не только с тем, что выборка по условию будет оптимизирована (напр. индексами), но и тем что вам не требуется выгружать из БД множество строк в вашу модель. А касательно вопроса: что именно вы собираетесь облегчать? Вам не нравится время загрузки? Вам не нравится, что ваше приложение зависает во время загрузки?

Comment: То что виснет во время загрузки, и запрос с множеством условий довольно много занимает времени

Comment: А вы пользуетесь возможностями записи, которые предоставляет QSqlTableModel?

Comment: Да, я могу сортировать модель по запроса sqltableModel и обновить данные,  бд довольно большая 1-1.5 млн записей  в 7 колонок, но если sqltableModel setFilter()  - тяжелый на несколько условий ; select() ; то бд буквально виснет на секунд 20 при первом запуске, но следующие запросы занимают уже 0.5 - 1 сек , хотя запрос ,такой же(видимо первый запрос подгружает бд в кеш или что то подобное)  , решения в том что бы перевести бд в другой поток особо не поможет ибо в qml эта бд служит для отображения информации как модель - делегат

Comment: Обновить данные — это обновить данные в модели или отредактировать данные в бд? Бд sqlite? Правильно я понимаю, что вы выгружаете таблицу с условиями, а потом хотите наложить доп фильтр, но не выгружать таблицу заново из бд? Какого рода фильтры? `LIKE` или обычные `<`, `>`?

Comment: Обновить данные модели, в бд я не лезу , только беру данные с неё,  фильтры на подобии диапазона значений или выбрать какие то определённые типы продуктов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема `QSqlTableModel` и `QSortFilterProxyModel` состоит в том, что их методы выполняются в gui потоке приложения. `QSortFilterProxyModel`, например, проходится по всем строкам модели-источника, что долго работает в случае, если строк в исходной модели много,`QSqlTableModel` долгое время выгружает большое количество строк и т.д.

Зачастую из-за этой особенности приходится писать свои реализации моделей, которые не так сильно нагружают gui поток.

Сначала хочу предложить ***ленивый способ*** убрать зависание.

В большинстве случаев зависания в qt появляются из-за того, что основной(gui) поток qt-приложения не входит в свой event loop. Его можно запустить вручную с помощью `QCoreApplication::processEvents`, однако [документация](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) не рекомендует этого делать. Конкретно в данном случае можно разбить выполнение вот этой строчки:

```
while(buildModel.canFetchMore()) buildModel.fetchMore();
```

Заведём сигнал и слот:

```
signals:
    void tryFetchMore();
private slots:
    void catchFetchMore() {
        if(canFetchMore()) {
            fetchMore();
            emit tryFetchMore();
        }
    }
```

В конструкторе коннектим:

```
connect(this, &MyModel::tryFetchMore, this, &MyModel::catchFetchMore, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Кода нам нужно выгрузить все данные вызываем:

```
emit tryFetchMore();
```

Таким образом мы гарантируем, что приложение хотя бы раз войдёт в event loop при прогрузке данных страницы. Это перестанет выглядеть как зависание, но интерфейс всё равно будет немного подтормаживать.

***Более правильным способом*** будет написать свою модель, которая бы принимала свои данные из другого потока.

Для наследования лучше выбрать `QAbstractTableModel`. Рекомендации по наследованию можно посмотреть [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstracttablemodel.html#subclassing).

Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы передавать через `signal`/`slot` указатели на данные модели. Таким образом можно свести к минимуму основные действия, которые совершает модель.

Например:

```
private slots:
    void updateModelData(MyModelData* data) {
        beginResetModel();
        data_ = data;
        rowCount_ = data->rowCount();
        endResetModel();       
    };
```

Зачастую будет удобнее передавать данные частями. В таком случае лучше использовать `beginInsertRows` и `endInsertRows`. Пусть модель запрашивает каждую следующую часть данных и передаёт/хранит некий индекс, который будет подтверждением того, что полученная часть данных относится к текущему запросу на обновление, а не к предыдущему.

Важно следить за тем, чтобы данные по указателю не терялись. Используйте либо умные указатели, либо пусть класс, обитающий в рабочем потоке, хранит их до соответствующей отмашки от модели.

Фильтрацию тоже лучше сделать самостоятельно (либо опять же оставить это бремя на бд). `QSortFilterProxyModel` делает это слишком долго т.к. попросту перебирает все строки. Для фильтров диапазона значений и выборок по полям очень удобно будет съимитировать индексы из бд (или попросту использовать индексацию в бд, которая ускорит запрос). Идея состоит в том, чтобы хранить значения полей, по которым будет проходить выборка в отсортированном порядке и держать рядом с ними указатели на соответствующие строки. В итоге вместо выборки по всем строкам вы будете находить необходимые для отображения строки путём бинарного поиска. Реализовать это более простым способом поможет `QMap` и методы `lowerBound` и `upperBound`. В идеале не изобретать велосипед и использовать возможности `sql` (в конце концов он для этого создан).

Это был лишь набор рекомендаций. Они не являются единственно верными и есть множество различных способов реализации. Каждая будет лучше в конкретном случае и нужно смотреть в текущей ситуации. Суть основной идеи: [**разгрузить gui поток**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-performance.html#timing-considerations).

> Как оказалось, `QSortFilterProxyModel` захватывает определенное количество данных при запросе, то есть захватывает не все сразу.

Это не `QSortFilterProxyModel` не захватывает все данные сразу, это `QSqlQueryModel` не считывает все данные в том случае, если используемый драйвер не реализует возвращения размера результата запроса (`QSortFilterProxyModel` просто прокидывает методы `canFetchMore` и `fetchMore` из модели источника). Например так работает движок `sqlite`. Для него в модель выгружается по 256 строк. Засчёт этого визуально данная модель будет работать более быстро, когда будут использоваться фильтры в запросе ибо в противном случае вам придётся выгрузить весь результат, чтобы отобразить его в `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Я использовал `sqlite` с 500 тыс. записей при множественных фильтрах `LIKE` и несколькими `JOIN`-ами. В результате первые 256 строк в модель прогружались достаточно быстро, чтобы не вызывать подвисаний графической части. Если запрос занимает много времени, возможно, стоит произвести индексацию данных в самой бд.

`QSortFilterProxyModel` стоит использовать, когда объём исходных данных небольшой, либо когда отношение исходных данных к данным в бд очень большое (и то стоит произвести предварительные замеры производительности).

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно в Бд около 1.7 млн записей, использовать QSortFilterProxyModel было глупой затеей, буду пытаться сделать то что Вы советовали, по поводу ленивого способа к сожалению он не сработал все так же висит ), попытаюсь сделать свою модель которая принимает данные с другого потока , как оказалось модели с потока в поток передать нельзя потому буду стараться передавать данные частями просто )